# Getting the right object references in jQuery to make validation work

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form in my admin panel and am having a bit of trouble with my references in jQuery.

The form code looks like this:

```
<div class="full-width">
    <label for="file_name-644" >File Name</label> 
    <span class="relative"><input type="text" name="file_name-644" id="file_name-644" class="full-width" disabled="disabled" value="pic.jpg"/><span ></span></span>
</div>
<div class="full-width">
    <label for="name-644" class="required">Name</label> 
    <span class="relative"><input type="text" name="name-644" id="name" value="" class="full-width name"/><span ></span></span>
</div>
```

now, as this form can have multiple entries processed at once, the numbers will change on the references (so from 644 to 108 for example). This is created with a php loop.

In jquery i'm using an `.each()` loop to check that the values are filled. Right now, all I need for validation is non-empty fields for the name. Currently, it looks like this:

```
$('.name').each(function(index) {
    if(!$(this).val()){ctr++;}else{error++;}
});
```

The variables `ctr` and `error` are counters that I later use to point out errors or how many entries are ready to be processed.

What I want to add to this is a change to the label for just the entries that are empty so that these stand out. I know I can change all of them with
`$('.required').css({'color': '#AB1414'});`
but how can I do this in the `.each()` loop above and just for the empty values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $('.name')  I cant see class="name" in your code can you paste your complete code

Comment: Also you should remove unnecessary </span> from your code

Comment: look again under the input `class="full-width name"` - it's there. Also the unnecessary span is actually used for something else w/javascript so needs to be there in this instance. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `.each()` loop in your code, you could do the following. Note that it uses [`jQuery.trim()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to consider values with only white space to be empty as well.

Using [`prev()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)  it also gets the previous `<label>` of its [`parent()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) , but *only* if it has the `required` class. Then in the `if()`, it checks the [`length`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property of the `<label>` object to see if there indeed was a `required` label.

```
$('.name').each(function(index) {
    var $th = $(this);
    if( $th.parent().prev('.required').length && !$.trim( $th.val() ) ){ctr++;}else{error++;}
});
```

Comment: excellent! thanks for the thorough explanation as well - will read up on those a bit more. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add required class for input fields rather than span and use this code on validation

```
 $('.required').each(function(){
       if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).css({'color': '#AB1414'});
    });
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. `.required` is a class on the label; `.name` is the class on the input. Wouldn't this just try and pull a value for the label (which doesn't have one)? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this for HTML:

```
<div class="full-width nameContainer">
    <label for="name-644" class="required">Name</label> 
    <span class="relative"><input type="text" name="name-644" id="name" value="" class="full-width name"/><span ></span></span>
</div>
```

And for JS:

```
$('.nameContainer').each(function(index) {
    var value = $(".name", this).val();
    if(!value)
    {
      $('.required', this).css({'color': '#AB1414'});
      ctr++;
    }
    else
    {
      error++;
    }
});
```